# I've just upgraded to Php7 now I'm having this issues

Tags: php

Problem 1
    - Installation request for phpunit/phpunit 5.7.14 -> satisfiable by phpunit/phpunit[5.7.14].
    - phpunit/phpunit 5.7.14 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.

Comment: I tried these codes sudo apt-get install php-xml,  sudo apt-get install php5.6-xml But Im still getting the same error

Comment: Pls read [How To Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a query in stackoverflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You most probably need to uninstall php5 extension and install php7.0-xml extension. 
Afterward restart apache2/nginx and you should be good to go!

Comment: Hi Simas, thanks for your immediate reply, FYI following a guide by using ondej's PPA I did sudo apt-get remove --purge php5, But still didnt work, whats the best way forward to this? is it  apt-get purge php5-common?

Comment: to my knowledge, purge php5 should remove all related files, but it can get a little wacky. that is why i suggested to first remove the package in question (php-xml) to see if it solves the issue. At least that had helped me to solve the similar issue in my project

Comment: Hi Again Simas, how to do that exactly? What line of code do i need for me to do that? If im being honest, Im now scared to encounter another problem really,since I was finally able to install Php7 composer and Laravel,but well  it took me sometime to figure out how to fix a lot of issues pertaining to installing these softwares.There's only one problem left mate, Hope to hearing from you soon. Thank you very much

Comment: assuming you are using a cloud provider (i.e. digital ocean) you can always make a snapshot in case you are afraid to mess something up (a clone of your instance). In a virtual machine or docker you can also make backups in a similar way (that's about the 'scared' part). Wht i meant you to try is `sudo apt-get remove php-xml` or `sudo apt-get remove php5.6-xml`, followed by `sudo api-get install php7.0-xml`. Afterwards restarting the web service (apache2/nginx).

Comment: Simas, Youre such a great Help!! It worked!! Thank you very much!! I can now continue working on my Laravel project... Again Thanks and Have a great week ahead!! Take care mate Cheers /.. Owen